# Where to set [Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)] in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android, android-9.0-pie

I have tried to put it above the MainActivity and(i know that) it doesnt fit there; build error:"The GenerateJavaStub task failed", But I dont know how to do it

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is an application class and you can then do this there,

Add a class that inherits from the Android Application class and then do something like below and it should work for you

```
[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
public class MainApplication: Application
{
```

Comment: but isnt MainActivity the starter

Comment: Yes but an application class is not a starter it is just the application-level configuration that you want

Comment: in github I have read that many similar aplication manifest attributes are not yet implemented. And i think it might take a while. Can u provide me with the same code.

Comment: Provide you with the same code? I am unable to understand what exactly do you want from me!

Answer (score 1):

In the shared project you should have the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. Add the following line at the end of the file:

```
[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
```

Let us know please if it worked for you, thanks.